# How to get Hogging Thread name WLST

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, wlst

I want to get names of thread marked as Hogger in weblogic. 
I have tried with 
ThreadPoolRuntimeMBean.getHoggingThreadCount()
but this gives only count of hogging threads.

Under Self- Tuning Thread Pool Threads
**Weblogic is displaying "Thread Name" ,"Stuck" (True/ false) and "Hogger" (True/ false)** , So obviously weblogic developer has written some method to get these values.

**I am looking for that weblogic inbuilt method (in WLST) or any other way to get names of hogging threads**.

PFA Weblogic Screen Shot for more detail
or check image on this link (http://www.munzandmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/st9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic WLST script to accomplish this (for a default non-clustered AdminServer installation):

```
connect('weblogic', 'welcome1')
serverRuntime()
cd('ThreadPoolRuntime/ThreadPoolRuntime')
for thread in cmo.getExecuteThreads():
   print(thread.getName() + " - " + str(thread.isHogger()))
```

You can use **print dir(thread)** to get all the available properties and methods.

For a more complex managed server environment, you can combine the above with this example: http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.co.za/2009/06/self-tuned-thread-pool-count.html#.ViCqTnVStBc

Comment: thanks Rudolfv, can you also help me with a list of all possible methods for thread reference in the for loop. eg: thread.getName() and thread.isHogger. I want to know full thread name, here by getName method I am getting "" [ACTIVE] Execute Thread: '0' for queue:
'weblogic.kernal.Default (self-tuning)'"" which doesn't signify anything. I would like to know the exact thread name. Please share all possible method or any reference for this concern.